# how to find the number of unique file extensions in a pandas data frame column(of file names)?

Tags: pandas

Need to get the number of unique file extensions from a column with thousands of files with extension(file1.txt , file2.txt, file3.csv, file4.jpg , ... ).

```
df[['filename']].loc[df['filename'].str.split().str.most_common(100)]
```

Answer (score 2):

ou can use the split method to split each file name by the period character and then extract the last element of the resulting list

```
data = {'filename': ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.csv', 'file4.jpg']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

file_extensions = df['filename'].str.split('.').str[-1].unique()
num_unique_extensions = len(file_extensions)

print(num_unique_extensions)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

> What should I do if i want to get the count of each extensions?

```
counts = df['filename'].str.rsplit('.', n=1).str[1].value_counts()
print(counts)

# Output
txt    2
csv    1
jpg    1
Name: filename, dtype: int64
```

---

You can split the filename from the end around last dot then use `unique` to get unique extensions or `nunique` to count unique extensions:

```
exts = df['filename'].str.rsplit('.', n=1).str[1].unique().tolist()
print(exts)
print(len(exts))

# Output
['txt', 'csv', 'jpg']
```

Or if you only want the number of extensions, use `nunique` instead of `unique`:

```
num = df['filename'].str.rsplit('.', n=1).str[1].nunique()
print(num)

# Output
3
```

Input:

```
>>> df
    filename
0  file1.txt
1  file2.txt
2  file3.csv
3  file4.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.what should I do if i want to get the count of each extensions?

Comment: @HAAAAN. I updated my answer according your comment.